# JQuery window opener is null

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery version `1.11.0`. For opening modal window my code is:

```
 var ActionTest = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var page = "/CalCalendar/ContactAddUpdate?iACCO_KEY=@iACCO_KEY&iIsModalDialog=1";

    var $dialog = $('#divModalHolder')
                   .html('<iframe style="border: 0px; " src="' + page + '" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>')
                   .dialog({
                     autoOpen: false,
                     modal: true,
                     height: 700,
                     width: "50%",
                     title: "Uredi stranko / kontakte stranke",
                     open: function () {
                       $(this).find('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').blur();
                     },
                   })

    $dialog.dialog('open');

  }
```

I would like to get reference to opener window inside my modal dialog. I've tried:

```
opener
```

and

```
window.opener
```

both are null. This is really strange to me, because `divModalHolder` is part of the website, where popup is opened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `parent`, not `opener`. So in the code in your iframe:

```
console.log(parent.location); // Would show the location of the container window
```

Comment: *(Ugh, cut-and-paste error. If you see `alert(opener.location)` above, hit refresh.)*

Comment: How can I get html of the parent? I would to search for elements inside parent, like this one $("#selectCONT_KEY")

Comment: @FrenkyB: That's a different question. First off, that's not getting the HTML of the parent. HTML is *markup*, it's text. You want to access elements in the parent window. You can do that by using the copy of jQuery that's in the parent window: `parent.$("#selectCONT_KEY")`

Comment: Thanks. I've already figured it out with this: $(parent.document).find("#selectCONT_KEY"); The syntax that you've provided - parent.$("#selectCONT_KEY") is new to me. Perhaps you have link or anything that I can read about it? Thank you again.

Comment: @FrenkyB: It's not new syntax. :-) `parent.$` gets the `$` property (the jQuery function) from `parent`. `("...")` then calls it. Since the version of jQuery loaded in the parent window will look in the parent window by default, it finds elements in that parent window. Yours works by calling the version of jQuery loaded in the iframe but telling it to use the other window's document. That works too. But you can do `var $p = parent.$;` and then us `$p` (`$p("#selectCONT_KEY")`) wherever you need to in the iframe...